# C# Why using instance method as delegate allocates GC0 temp objects but 10% faster than a cached delegate

Tags: c#, .net, performance, inline

I am currently optimizing a low-level library and have found a counter-intuitive case. The commit that caused this question is [here](https://github.com/buybackoff/Aeron.NET/commit/3fb7a382d8c774e007b96f73e061a97f9473321d).

There is a delegate

```
public delegate void FragmentHandler(UnsafeBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Header header);
```

and an instance method

```
public void OnFragment(IDirectBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Header header)
{
    _totalBytes.Set(_totalBytes.Get() + length);
}
```

On [this line](https://github.com/buybackoff/Aeron.NET/blob/3fb7a382d8c774e007b96f73e061a97f9473321d/src/Samples/Adaptive.Aeron.Samples.IpcThroughput/IpcThroughput.cs#L159), if I use the method as a delegate, the program allocates many GC0 for the temp delegate wrapper, but the performance is 10% faster (but not stable).

```
var fragmentsRead = image.Poll(OnFragment, MessageCountLimit);
```

If I instead cache the method in a delegate outside the loop like this:

```
FragmentHandler onFragmentHandler = OnFragment;
```

then the program does not allocate at all, numbers are very stable but much slower.

I looked through generated IL and it is doing the same thing, but in the later case `newobj` is called only once and then local variable if loaded.

With cached delegate IL_0034:

```
IL_002d: ldarg.0
IL_002e: ldftn instance void Adaptive.Aeron.Samples.IpcThroughput.IpcThroughput/Subscriber::OnFragment(class [Adaptive.Agrona]Adaptive.Agrona.IDirectBuffer, int32, int32, class [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.Header)
IL_0034: newobj instance void [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.FragmentHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_0039: stloc.3
IL_003a: br.s IL_005a
// loop start (head: IL_005a)
    IL_003c: ldloc.0
    IL_003d: ldloc.3
    IL_003e: ldsfld int32 Adaptive.Aeron.Samples.IpcThroughput.IpcThroughput::MessageCountLimit
    IL_0043: callvirt instance int32 [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.Image::Poll(class [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.FragmentHandler, int32)
    IL_0048: stloc.s fragmentsRead
```

With temp allocations IL_0037:

```
IL_002c: stloc.2
IL_002d: br.s IL_0058
// loop start (head: IL_0058)
    IL_002f: ldloc.0
    IL_0030: ldarg.0
    IL_0031: ldftn instance void Adaptive.Aeron.Samples.IpcThroughput.IpcThroughput/Subscriber::OnFragment(class [Adaptive.Agrona]Adaptive.Agrona.IDirectBuffer, int32, int32, class [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.Header)
    IL_0037: newobj instance void [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.FragmentHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_003c: ldsfld int32 Adaptive.Aeron.Samples.IpcThroughput.IpcThroughput::MessageCountLimit
    IL_0041: callvirt instance int32 [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.Image::Poll(class [Adaptive.Aeron]Adaptive.Aeron.LogBuffer.FragmentHandler, int32)
    IL_0046: stloc.s fragmentsRead
```

Why the code with allocations is faster here? What is needed to avoid allocations but keep the performance?

(testing on .NET 4.5.2/4.6.1, x64, Release, on two different machines)

**Update**

Here is standalone example that behaves as expected: cached delegate performs more than 2x faster with 4 sec vs 11 sec. So the question is specific to the referenced project - what subtle issues with JIT compiler or something else could cause the unexpected result?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestCachedDelegate {

    public delegate int TestDelegate(int first, int second);

    public static class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tc = new TestClass();
            tc.Run();
        }

        public class TestClass {

            public void Run() {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                    CallDelegate(Add, i, i);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Non-cached: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Restart();
                TestDelegate dlgCached = Add;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                    CallDelegate(dlgCached, i, i);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Cached: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            public int CallDelegate(TestDelegate dlg, int first, int second) {
                return dlg(first, second);
            }

            public int Add(int first, int second) {
                return first + second;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you post a [MCVE] of your problem which isn't related to your domain specific code, so this can be reproduced on other machines.

Comment: Your commit is a bit unclear, introducing a variable with the same name as the class field except for the leading underscore, and the old version referring to the class field. You're sure you've tested with the local variable, I hope?

Comment: @hvd Local variable inside the loop behaves the same as using the method inside the `.Poll()` function. Local variable outside the loop behaves similarly to a field.

Comment: That hot wait-loop with Thread.Yield() is *very* ugly, it voids any kind of execution determinism.  Burning through the thread quantum is going to put you in the dog house for a while.  The heap lock that the *new* operator needs to take can help.

Comment: @hvd In that commit, the comment explains what happens. I tried different combinations - a field and a local variable, which result in the same behavior. A cached delegate is slower no matter where it is cached, allocation inside the loop is faster no matter if I create a variable inside the loop or pass the instance method directly to the Poll function.

Comment: @HansPassant That yield is only at a startup phase and is not consequential. There are probably quite a few people who could give any hint, and you are one of them. I am not asking for a complete solution, but the behavior I am seeing is weird and I am lost in direction. What JIT could do differently here compared to the trivial sample that behaves as expected?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5835

Comment: On my (much slower machine i5 CPU), I get different results 45.242sec (non-cached) vs 33.952sec (cached). What is your hardware config and how do you test it?

Comment: There is a PR in that project with probable explanation. I am on Mac Air latest model with 8Gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reading the question much too quickly and thinking the it was asking something else I've finally had some time to sit down and play with the Aeoron test in question.

I tried a few things, first of all I compared the IL and Assembler produced and found that there was basically no difference at either the site where we call `Poll()` or at the site where the handler is actually called.

Secondly I tried commenting out the code in the `Poll()` method to confirm that the cached version did actually run faster (which it did).

Thridly I tried looking at the CPU counters (Cache misses, instructions retired and branch mis-predictions) in the VS profiler but could not see any differences between the two version other than the fact that the delegate constructor obviously was called more times.

This made me think about a similar case that we ran accross in porting [Disruptor-net](https://github.com/disruptor-net/Disruptor-net) where we had a test that was running slower than the java version but we were sure we weren't doing anything more costly.  The reason for the "slowness" of the test was that we were actually faster and therefore batched less and therefore our throughput was lower.

If you insert a Thread.SpinWait(5) just before the call to `Poll()` you will see the same or better performance as the non-cached version.

**Original answer to the question which I thought at the time was "why using an instance method delegate is slower than caching the delegate manually":**

The clue is in the question.  It's an instance method and therefore it implicitly captures the `this` member and the fact that this is captured means that it cannot be cached.  Given that `this` will never change during the lifetime of the cached delegate it should be cacheable.

If you expand the method group to `(first, second) => this.Add(first, second)` the capture becomes more obvious.

Note that the Roslyn team is working on fixing this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5835

Comment: How this answers the question!?

Comment: @V.B. I hadn't read the question properly, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting